# Solving $u_t+u^2u_x=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristic-functions

I'm trying to solve the initial value problem with characteristis.:
$$
u_t+u^2\cdot u_x=0\quad,\quad u(0,x)=f(x)
$$
Where $u$ is a neat function with suitable requirements on its domain and its behaviour as my book says. I am unbelievably akward when it comes to solving with characteristics, so I hope that you can help me solving this.

---

**What I did**

First of all, a characteristic line is a line $(X(t),t)$ such that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}X(t) \ = \ u(X(t))^2
$$

I read that $u$ does not change on characteristic lines, so $u^2$ shouldn't change either, which means that:
$$
X(t) \ = \ u(t,X(t))^2t +k \ = \ u(0,X(0))^2t +k \ = \ f(X(0))^2\cdot t+k 
$$
Where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is a value vanishing when taking the derivative.
I thougt that I could find $X(0)$ just by filling in:
$
 \ X(0) \ = \ u(0,X(0))^2 \cdot 0 +k \ = \ k
$, which gives us the following:
$$
X(t) \ = \ f(k)^2\cdot t +k 
$$
If we want to find $u(t_0,x_0)$ for an arbitrary point $(t_0,x_0)$ in the domain, we have to follow the characteristic line back to the place where $t=0$, where we know what the function looks like. So:
$$
u(t_0,x_0) \ = \ u(0,x_0 - t_0f(k)^2) \ = \ f(x_0 - t_0 f(k)^2)
$$
Where a suitable $k$ still has to be found. But that means that the intersection point we are looking for is $k$, and the value we are looking for is $f(k)$.

---

I guess this might be solvable when $f$ is given, but that's not the case here. Can you help me to solve this?

---

Comment: why is $u$ identically zero not a solution?

Comment: Well, it is. Do you claim that it is the only one?

Comment: where is the solution going to come from? you have zero  initial data and zero forcing. i really can see what is going to produce a non zero response.

Comment: **Note** This question has been through an overhaul. The comments above are about the question as it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, I answered to the question : [Quasi-linear PDE with Cauchy conditions:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310135/quasi-linear-pde-with-cauchy-conditions/1310293#1310293)

where the PDE was : 
$$u_t+uu_x=0 \text{   with condition  }u(x,0)=\phi(x) $$
This was solved thanks to a change of variable, or alternatively with the method of characteristics, both leading to the solution on implicit form:
$$u=\phi (x-ut)$$

Refering to my previous answer, the similar calculus for the new PDE :
$$u_t+u^2u_x=0 \text{   with condition  }u(x,0)=f(x) $$
will lead to the solution on implicit form :
$$u=f(x-u^2t)$$